# How to load template Angular and render it?

Tags: angular

The Load method looks like:

```
private renderTemplate() {
    fetch(`${this.libraryUrl}/assets/object.template.mustache`, {
        cache: 'no-cache',
        mode: 'cors',
    })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((template) => {
            document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = template;
        });
}
```

Template file is Angular's:

```
<div
   class="ObjectDetailsFromItem"
   *ngFor="let field of object | fieldhaschanges: initialObject:showVersions | objectfieldsarray"
   >
   <ng-container [ngSwitch]="field?.htmlInputAttr?.type">
      <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="'a-img'">
         <a href="{{ object.panoramaHref }}" target="panoramas3d"> Панорама </a>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngSwitchDefault>
         <label>{{ field.name }}</label>
         <div
            class="ObjectDetailsFromItemValue"
            [ngClass]="{ firstClass: true, yeallow: field.field === 'UNOM', hasChanges: field.hasChanges }"
            >
            {{ field.value }}
         </div>
      </ng-template>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Container where I try to place loaded template:

```
 <div id="target"></div>
```

So, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

First of you don't need to write any code to render your template in angular 2+. Everything is handled by the framework itself. When you generate a component in your angular project there will be four files.

1. app.component.ts file for your component logic
2. app.component.spec.ts file for your unit test cases
3. app.component.html for your template
4. app.component.css for your style sheets

On the top of the class generated class there will be annotation as given below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

The above code will take care of loading your template. Even if you are creating a child component there will be a similar structure, if you want to use that component you can use.

```
<div><app-child></app-child></div>
```

Please refer the heroes example in the [getting started](https://angular.io/start) documentation of angular. This will give you clearer idea on how to get started, I suggest you refer this documentation before you go forward.